# read line with fgets() rewind(File * file) does not work?

Tags: c, fgets

```
char *readLine(int n, char * filename) 
{
FILE * file=fopen(filename,"r");
int i=0;
int BUF=255;
char temp[BUF];
char puffer[BUF];
char* returned_string;
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
if(fgets(temp, BUF, file) == NULL)
    return NULL;

if(fgets(puffer,BUF,file) == NULL)
return NULL;

returned_string = malloc (strlen (puffer) + 1);
strcpy (returned_string, puffer);
rewind(file); 
fclose(file);
return returned_string;
}
```

calling previous code with :

```
char * temp=readLine(0,filename);
char * temp2=readLine(1,filename);
char * temp3=readLine(2,filename);
```

makes all three variables the same although i am trying to read different lines with different content..

I also tried to use rewind(File * file) which should be the same as fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET)

How can I read the lines i want to read?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A file is not a tape. You are "rewinding" it but that does not make sense if you next *close* it. The operation only makes sense on an open file. But it isn't what you are after, is it? You do *not* want to restart reading from the start again?

Comment: The `fseek` you posted is not equivalent to a `rewind`. It's also not needed since you close the `FILE *` anyway.

Comment: thank you i corrected the fseek. 
I want to restart reading the file! I agree that rewind does not make sense here but it temp temp2 and temp3 have all the same value no matter rewind(file) is called or not.

Comment: Use a debugger, and step though the code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you call the function with `n` as 0 or 1, you're going to get the first line in the file. If `n` is 0 or 1 and `i` is 0, then `i` is not less than `n - 1`, so your `for` loop will never execute.

The function should, however, correctly return the second line when called with n as 2. It works for me:

Input file:

```
Test line 1
Test line 2
Test line 3
Test line 4
Test line 5
```

Calls:

```
int main (void) {

    char *str0, *str1, *str2;

    str0 = readLine (0, "test");
    str1 = readLine (1, "test");
    str2 = readLine (2, "test");

    printf ("%s%s%s\n", str0, str1, str2);

return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Test line 1
Test line 1
Test line 2
```

So if it isn't working for you, I suspect some corruption in your input file; or the first two lines of the file are the same.

Also, `rewind(file)` is redundant in your code.

Comment: Hello verbose. Could you also try to call readLine(3, "test");

Comment: The one you currently have. If you keep editing and reverting your code after you ask the question, it becomes difficult to answer.

Comment: I AM SHOCKED IT REALLY WORKS.

Comment: Please try to make your code more elegant by getting rid of one of the two buffers; you don't need both `buffer` and `puffer`. How can you streamline it by using only one of the two? (Left as an exercise for you to figure out.)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

try this code instead it goes to the nth line and returns it (I believe that this is what you want to do) fseek goes to the line before and fgets gets the line that follows (meaning the targeted line) :

```
char *readLine(int n, char * filename) 
{
FILE * file=fopen(filename,"r");
int i=0;
int BUF=255;
char puffer[BUF];
char* returned_string;
fseek(file , n-1 ,SEEK_SET);
if(fgets(puffer,BUF,file) == NULL)
    return NULL;
returned_string = malloc(sizeof(puff));
strcpy (returned_string, puffer);
fclose(file);
return returned_string;
}
```

in malloc use `malloc(sizeof(puff)) or malloc(BUFF)` for it is much faster because when you use `malloc(strlen(puff) + 1)` the compiler has to calculate strlen(puff) every time

Comment: i do not have a problem in rereading the single lines. This is not a performance issue. I want to call this function from anywhere at anytime to open the file and see what is written in line 20019 for example. As I understood you are trying to save the last position to read the file from this position at the next call.

Comment: so you're trying to write a function that works a bit like fseek right ?

Comment: Maybe. I am trying to write a function which returns me the content of a certain line of a file. No matter when or where I call it.

Comment: I updated my answer try and see if the new code works for you

Comment: no problem , but here's a tip , next time instead of wasting memory space with variables you don't need like BUF just use a symbolic constant like this : `#define BUF 255`

Answer (score 1):

The entire `rewind` is a red herring (a deliberate obfuscation). It seems to me the only problem is that your main "skip line" loop is not correct. Try this in the for..loop instead:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Since you want to *read* line `n`, you have to *skip* lines `0..n-1`. Your for-loop ended one line too early.

Comment: I tried this. char * temp3=readLine(2,filename); returns NULL now but line 3rd line in the file is 0\n. :S